# Why is Global.asax.cs Application_Error executed twice (in this instance)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

To take a step back, I'm mucking around learning about ASP.NET Error Handling and I was specifically looking at this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/aspnet-error-handling

And I have their WingtipToys project downloaded.

This led me to do the following (Visual Studio 2013, .NET 4.5):

1. New Project - ASP.NET Web Application (I named it EmptyWebApp).

   a. On the next screen of this Wizard, I selected Empty, and for Add folders and core references for, I ensured that Web Forms, MVC, Web API were all unchecked.
2. Added a New Web Form (named WebForm1).

The code in the .cs looks like this:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new Exception("foo");
    }
}
```

3. Added a New Web Form (named ErrorPage), i left the default html code other than adding "I am an error page!" in between the div tags.

The code in the .cs looks like this:

```
public partial class ErrorPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Server.ClearError();
    }
}
```

4. Added a New Global Application Class

The only function with code is this:

```
    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();

        Server.Transfer("ErrorPage.aspx");
    }
```

(Yes, exc does nothing right now, but I was planning on using it).

When I compile and run (with breakpoints on Server.Transfer and Server.ClearError in the ErrorPage), I notice that the breakpoint is hit twice.

It does the following:

```
a. Server.Transfer (in Application_Error)
b. Server.ClearError (in Page_Load of ErrorPage)
c. Server.Transfer (in Application_Error)
d. Server.ClearError (in Page_Load of ErrorPage)
```

**So, it's transfered twice, and the Page Loads twice.**

First time I get to the Server.Transfer breakpoint (a.), exc has a value.
Second time I get to the Server.Transfer breakpoint (c.), exc is null.

Commenting out the Server.ClearError, it doesn't load twice.

Placing Server.ClearError right after the Server.Transfer, again, we are back to loading twice.

Removing the Server.Transfer (in Application_Error) and just keeping the Server.ClearError(), and it executes once.

So, some combination of Sever.Transfer and Server.ClearError is causing this.

But, when I run the WingTipToys project, they have a Server.ClearError in their Page_Load, and it doesn't cause Application_Error to get executed twice.  I mean, if it's executing twice, is there some error happening (that I can't explain)?

I suppose it's not a big deal, but it gives me pause that my simple project exhibits different run-time behaviors.

Thanks!